# Aggregate value by any of two columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Suppose I have a Customers Table:

```
Customers
-----------------------------------------------
Id INTEGER
SSN NCHAR(11)
FullName NVARCHAR(100)
LastPurchaseDate DATETIME
```

There are many stores around the city, and the customer can be registered in any of them, each one giving him a different `Id`. Wherever he buys, the corresponding `Id` gets it's `LastPurchaseDate` updated.

Now I need to get the `Id` corresponding to the 'latest' `LastPurchaseDate` **by person**. Problem is, due to X different reasons, there can be typos on either the `SSN` or the `FullName`. Let's say I have the next data:

```
Id          SSN            FullName      LastPurchaseDate
----------- -----------    ------------- -----------------
200123      123-45-6789    John Doe      10-09-2015 
201978      456-78-9012    Mary Jane     15-08-2015 
380789      789-01-2345    Pete Zahut    01-08-2015 
389236      123-45-6789    Jhon Doe      23-07-2015 
215875      456-87-9012    Mary Jane     30-08-2015 
974186      123456789      John Doe      28-04-2015 
123758      789-01-2345    Pete Zaut     18-08-2015
```

A customer is considered to be the same person if it has either the same `SSN` or the same `FullName`. So in this sample, customers `200123`, `389236` and `974186` are the same person. Therefore, the resulting `Id`s should be

```
200123
215875
123758
```

How can I achieve this?

**Edit**

So, the match has to be on either `SSN` or `FullName`, but it has to be exact; if both fields are different, even if it's by one character, it will be considered a different person. I hope the data will be eventually cleansed but it'll take it's time as it is a lot of info to trace and correct.

Comment: Sounds like you need **Data Cleansing**, in pure SQL it will be hard to do. Also matching in groups isn't trivial (depends on data) and may need human to supervise it

Comment: One way to normalize SSN could be `REPLACE(SSN, '-', '')` but for names it isn't so easy, you can try compare `LEN` as one metric, check also [SOUNDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) and `Levenshtein distance`

Comment: Imagine you have these rows: `ID=1`, `SSN=123`, `Name=ABC`; `ID=2`, `SSN=123`, `Name=ABD`; `ID=3`, `SSN=124`, `Name=ABD`; `ID=4`, `SSN=124`, `Name=ABE`; `ID=5`, `SSN=125`, `Name=ABE`... and so on... Should all of them be merged into one row? `ID=1` and `ID=5` have nothing in common, but there is a chain of other IDs that connects them.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov "yes and no" or "not really"; it's not required that the query considers `ID=1` and `ID=5` as the same person because they are not directly related.

Answer (score 0):

The first data cleaning will be:

```
(select REPLACE(SSN, '-', '') as SSN ,
Min(Id) as Id, Max(FullName) as FullName
max(LastPurchaeDate) as LastPurchaeDate
from Customers group by 1)
```

That will merge all the SSN numbers. In addition, it will go on the assumption that the lowest Id is the real Id and made max on name to avoid nulls. 
You can go to further purification by assuming that the longer name length is the better by Length functions.